# HTML Button Refreshes Page Instead of Sending Data to DB

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In my `index.html`, I have a `button` that I've used previously to submit data which is then sent to my DB. However, I've recently changed the layout to include tabs which rely on `CSS`.

Now, the same `button` only refreshes the page and does not do anything with the data. I've tried changing the `button` type, `form`, adding `evt.preventDefault()`, etc.. to no avail.

Here is a `form` of my `index.html`, I've reduced some reiterations of the tabs for the sake of convenience.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html ng-app>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/3.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
     <script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>  
     <% include header %> 
     <% include navbar %>
     <p>
     extra &nbsp;&nbsp; space
     <body>
     <!-- tabs -->
     <div class="pcss3t pcss3t-effect-scale pcss3t-theme-1">
     <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" checked  id="tab1"class="tab-content-first">
     <label for="tab1"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>Client</label>
     <!-- tab contents -->
     <li class="tab-content tab-content-3 typography">
     <!-- /container -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#home').addClass("active");
     });
     </script>
     <h1>Clients</h1>
     <div class="container">
     <div ng-controller="ClientCtrl">
     <span>{{remaining()}} of {{clients.length}} remaining</span> [ <a
     href="" ng-click="archive()">archive</a> ]
     <ul class="unstyled">
     <li ng-repeat="client in clients"><input type="checkbox"
     ng-model="client.done"> <span class="done-{{client.done}}">{{client.text}}
     </span>
     </li>
     </ul>
     <form ng-submit="addClient()">
     <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="clientText"
     size="30" placeholder="add new client here"> <spanclass="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button">Add</button>
     </span>
     </div>
     </div>
     </form>
     </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller form:

```
 function ClientCtrl($scope, $http) {
 $scope.clients = [];
 $http.get('/client').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.clients = data;
    if (data == "") {
        $scope.clients = [];
    }
 }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("Ops: could not get any data");
 });
 }
 }
 $scope.addClient = function() {
    $http.post('/client', {
        text : $scope.clientText,
        done : false,
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.clients.push({
            text : $scope.clientText,
            done : false
        });
        $scope.clientText = '';
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Ops: " + data);
    });
 };

 $scope.remaining = function() {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.clients, function(client) {
        count += client.done ? 0 : 1;
    });
    return count;
 };

 $scope.archive = function() {
    var oldClients = $scope.clients;
    $scope.clients = [];
    angular.forEach(oldClients, function(client) {
        if (!client.done)
            $scope.clients.push(client);
    });
 };
 }
```

The message received in command prompt when clicking the button results to:

```
GET / 304 2ms
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1ms
GET /js/todo.js 404 0ms
GET /js/todo.js 404 0ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form submit handler (`ng-submit`, or `onsubmit`) is designed to submit data to the path supplied in the form's `action` attribute.  With no attribute the data is submitted to the current address, and the page will refresh.

To avoid the default behavior, the method you call from ng-submit must return false.  This will prevent the redirect from occurring, and allow your scope changes to be persisted.

```
$scope.addClient = function() {
  $http.post('/client', {
    text : $scope.clientText,
    done : false,
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.clients.push({
        text : $scope.clientText,
        done : false
    });
    $scope.clientText = '';
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("Ops: " + data);
  });
  return false;
};
```

n.b. Based on you description, since the data isn't updated after the page refresh by calling GET on the  /client endpoint, there's probably something off with your persistence or data retrieval. Your implementation should store the data with the post() call and then retrieve it with the get() call when the page reloads.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it did not work. I removed the tab design from the html, and this did the trick. There is animation on tabs, given by CSS, would that be confusing the action of the submit button and turning it into an animation ?

Comment: I'm surprised that resolved the issue; tabs affecting the button click in this scenario doesn't seem very likely, unless something wacky is going on. For instance if your click handler for the tabs is gobbling up the click event for the submit button.

Comment: That must be the case, I've yet to find a way for them to coexist, unfortunately.

Comment: In my command prompt these are the results from clicking the button:                                                                                                        GET / 304 2ms
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1ms
GET /js/client.js 404 0ms
GET /js/client.js 404 0ms

Comment: Since your button is not type="submit" it will not submit the form, and ng-submit won't fire the method.  Try either changing the type to submit, or attaching the addClient() to ng-click on the button directly, rather than the form.